# Why group by $variable/@attribute doesn't work?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xquery-3.0, flwor

**Problem background**

Given the categories from each family...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <family>
        <categories>
            <cat id="1" />
            <cat id="2" />
        </categories>
    </family>
    <family>
        <categories>
            <cat id="3" />
            <cat id="5" />
        </categories>
    </family>
    <family>
        <categories>
            <cat id="3" />
            <cat id="5" />
            <cat id="6" />
        </categories>
    </family>
</root>
```

I want the categories that families have most in common...

```
<common-family-category id="3" count="2"/>
<common-family-category id="5" count="2"/>
```

**Successful tries**

I could achieve that result by grouping each iterated id...

```
for $family-category-id in //family/categories/cat/@id
count $return-indexes
group by $family-category-id
order by count($return-indexes) descending
where count($return-indexes) > 1
return
<common-family-category id="{$family-category-id}" count="{count($return-indexes)}" />
```

And also by iterating each category and storing the id in a variable...

```
for $family-category in //family/categories/cat
let $family-category-id := $family-category/@id
count $return-indexes
group by $family-category-id
order by count($return-indexes) descending
where count($return-indexes) > 1
return
<common-family-category id="{$family-category-id}" count="{count($return-indexes)}" />
```

**Failed tries**

But I couldn't achieve that by iterating the category and directly grouping the id...

```
for $family-category in //family/categories/cat
count $return-indexes
group by $family-category/@id
order by count($return-indexes) descending
where count($return-indexes) > 1
return
<common-family-category id="{$family-category/@id}" count="{count($return-indexes)}" />
```

It gives the following error in the `group by $family-category/@id`:

> [XPST0003] Expecting valid expression after 'group by'

**Question**

Since setting `$family-category/@id` into `$family-category-id` and grouping it worked...

Why grouping by `$family-category/@id` directly doesn't work?

And if that really shouldn't work, what's the reason for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially there are two forms of grouping clause in XQuery 3.0

The general form is

```
group by $var := key-expression
```

where $var defines the variable that will refer to the group, and key-expression is the expression that computes the grouping key.

If you find yourself writing

```
group by $var := $var
```

then you can abbreviate this to the more convenient shorthand

```
group by $var
```

But you can't write

```
group by key-expression
```

without declaring a grouping variable, except in the special case where the key expression is a simple variable reference.